# cron script won't reboot as it should

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a VPN via openvpn. Periodically, the connection drops, so I use the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep openvpn
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
        /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

I added it to crontab (using `sudo crontab -e`), I want the script to be executed every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/openvpn/check.sh
```

The script doesn't work, but it still seems to be executed every five minutes:

```
tail /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

gives:

```
Mar 16 21:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[11113]: (root) CMD (/etc/openvpn/check.sh)
...
```

Moreover, when I run the script manually with `sudo ./check.sh`, the Pi reboots just like it should.

I don't really understand what's going on here ?

**Edit** :

As suggested, I added the full path names and went from rebooting the Pi to restarting openvpn:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if ! /bin/ps -ef | /bin/grep '[o]penvpn'; then
        cd /etc/openvpn/
        /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/config.ovpn
fi
```

The script still doesn't work, although it runs fine when I execute it myself. The script's permissions are 755, so it should be ok ?

Comment: Consider using `killall -0 openvpn`. If the process exists you'll have $? equals to zero. Perhaps it's permission problem so the user who's crontab you edit isn't allowed to perform shutdown operation. Try to put `bash -x /etc/openvpn/check.sh 2>&1 | logger -t OPENVPNCHECK` into crontab.

Comment: You might need to set the path in your check.sh, since cron doesn't run with the user PATH, or use absolute paths.

Comment: @frist I used `sudo crontab -e` (sorry, should have clarified in the question), so I don't think there should be any permission problem ?

Comment: why restart?! can't just reconnect vpn?

Comment: Did you set the permissions on check.sh to something like 750?

Comment: In the script, add the full paths to the binaries, so /bin/ps, etc. (obtain them with a command like 'which grep', etc.).

Comment: @Roadowl that's a reasonable debugging technique, but the final script should just make sure it runs with a sane `PATH`, and not hard-code command paths. (And use `type`, not `which`.)

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I'll try using the `keepalive`setting when starting openvpn first, and I'll modify the script to include binary paths. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood why the script didn't work. Since it was located under `/etc/openvpn`, the condition `if ! ps -ef | grep -q '[o]penvpn'` wouldn't return `true` because of the script being executed. I noticed it when I changed the crontab line to:

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/openvpn/check.sh >/home/pi/output 2>/home/pi/erroutput
```

the `output` file showed the `/etc/openvpn/check.sh` script being run.

---

The script now is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if ! pidof openvpn; then
        cd /etc/openvpn/
        /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/config.ovpn
fi
```

and this works just fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

The *path name* of the script matches the final `grep` so it finds itself, and is satisfied.

The reason this didn't happen interactively was that you didn't run it with a full path.

This is (a twist on) a very common FAQ.

Tangentially, your script contains two very common antipatterns. You are reinventing `pidof` poorly, and you are examining `$?` explicitly. Unless you specifically require the exit code to be 1, you should simply be doing

```
if ! ps -ef | grep -q '[o]penvpn'; then
```

because the *purpose* of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code; and notice also the trick to use a regex which doesn't match itself. But using `pidof` also lets you easily examine just the binary executable's file name, not its path.

Comment: Rebooting when a process dies also seems excessively brutal. Is there a reason you don't simply restart it?

Comment: actually, there's no real reason, I just thought it'd be easier this way. Thanks, I will change my script when I get home